# Displaying the legend as text alongside marker in an area chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image]

Info: This is a visualization where Y axis is a decimal attribute, the X axis is years, and the PID's are represented in the legend with the markers. I used two visualizations on top of each other with the same visualization configuration, and increased transparency to see both of them. The area chart represents the average of the decimal attribute by year. And a chart on top of it represents the year and decimal attribute of the PID.

1 - I want to be able to show a text alongside the marker (the PID under every marker). I know it shows the PID and all the attributes when you hover over the specific marker, but the former is requested.

2 - The way I built my visualization is sloppy. I want to be able to mesh this information in a single chart if possible. Am I able to do this in PowerBI env? With dax, python etc. I'm fairly new to the software.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Solved the first problem. Found out about Data Labels.